# Force time to stay put

Tags: centos, date, time, ntp

The time on my Linux machine will not stay put. I need to test an issue with our server that only occurs on Saturdays.

- CentOS 6.5 64-bit
- I have NTPD off. (`service ntpd stop` and `chkconfig ntpd off`)
- I have the virtual BIOS/ HW clock set to May 2, 2015
- Changing the time to future or past has the same effect.
- I set the date on the command line with `date --set "02 May 2015 11:00:00"`
- `date` replies properly and shows the date is May 2 2015
- Nothing related to time/ntp in `cron.d`, `cron.daily`, `cron.hourly`, etc.

After a few minutes the time will force itself back to the proper date.

What else could be running to continually change the time back?
Where is it getting its info!?

Comment: And i thought my job was hard, here you are trying to stop time...

Comment: Is this a virtual guest? If so, it's possible the clock is actually synchronised to the host, and therefore outside your control.

Comment: Do you have systemtap installed? It can be used to trace the stime and settimeofday system calls and identify which process is making the call.

Comment: @JohnWHSmith Sorry, I'm using the iPad stack exchange app, and it didn't show your answer until just now! Your answer is nice because it's more portable - no packages to install.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick And I... deleted my comment too early (*I said SystemTap took a lot of fun away from my solution*). But let's face it: `stap` is just another toy I didn't know I had on my system, and I'm definitely going to play with it a lot now... so thanks :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this answer, I'll assume that there may be several elements working hard to set your time straight. Since I don't really want to wild-guess about *which one* is working against you, I'll try and give you an answer which should help you find it yourself instead.

On a UNIX system, the clock can typically be set using the `stime` system call. As things evolved, it also became possible to set the clocks more accurately using the `clock_settime` call instead. You might also come accross `settimeofday`. When running `date --set` on a CentOS machine, `strace` revealed that it used `clock_settime`.

Knowing this, a solution would be to trace these system calls. Good thing is, Linux has a mechanism for that: debugfs. On my system, calling `mount`, I can see that this is available at `/sys/kernel/debug` :

```
$ mount
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
...
```

However, on some systems (including RedHat and probably CentOS), [it isn't mounted at boot time](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_MRG/2/html/Realtime_Tuning_Guide/sect-Realtime_Tuning_Guide-Realtime_Specific_Tuning-Mount_debugfs.html). You'll therefore need to run...

```
# mount -t debugfs nodev /sys/kernel/debug
```

Also note that if you were in that directory before mounting, you might have to go out and back in before files start to appear in it.

Now we're ready to go. Let's enable the trace for our systems calls. I'm tracing all of them because I don't really want to check which one is really being used. Tracing for system calls can be set in `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/syscalls`. In this directory, you should find...

- `sys_enter_stime`
- `sys_enter_clock_settime`
- `sys_enter_settimeofday`

... depending on what's available on your system.

These correspond to the events of *entering* our system calls, which is what we want to trace (you'll also find `sys_exit_*` directories). Within each directory, you'll find a file named `enable`, the contents of which should appear to be 0. To trace these calls, set that to 1 instead:

```
# echo 1 > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/syscalls/sys_enter_stime/enable
# echo 1 > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/syscalls/sys_enter_clock_settime/enable
# echo 1 > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/syscalls/sys_enter_settimeofday/enable
```

Now that we've set up our trap, just wait until something sets your time to its correct value. Once it has happened, run for the trace logs at...

```
# cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace
```

Now, unless something wrong occured, you should see one of the following lines:

```
stime-xxxxx [xxx] .... x.x: sys_stime(...)
clock_settime-xxxxx [xxx] .... x.x: sys_clock_settime(...)
settimeofday-xxxxx [xxx] .... x.x: sys_settimeofday(...)
```

The number right after `stime-` (or another call's name) is the PID of the process which made the system call. Now go get it:

```
# ps -fp xxxxx
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root     XXXXX XXXXX  0 hh:mm ?        hh:mm:ss time_warrior
```

You should now have everything you need to make sure your system stops getting the time right. The simplest thing would probably be to kill the process, and make sure it isn't spawned at boot time ; of course, you'll have to make sure it doesn't serve a more *important* purpose before doing so : you don't want to completely crash your system...

Also remember to disable the trace when you're done by writing 0 to the files we edited earlier. A shortcut could be:

```
# echo 0 > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/syscalls/enable
```

(this file acts as a *master switch* for all others ; it allows you to switch all system calls tracing off)

---

*Note:* as Mark Plotnick said in a comment `systemtap` could be a slightly easier way to achieve similar results. I'll let him write a `stap` answer if he feels like it, since I'm not fluent with `stap` scripts at all.

Comment: Thank you for the extremely helpful and in depth troubleshooting help. I was able to determine vmtoolsd (vmware tools) was running and caused a time check which pulls info from vcenter server.

Answer (score 1):

If you have [systemtap](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/) installed, which is likely the case on a CentOS system, it's easy to trace any system call system-wide.

```
# cat clock.stp
probe nd_syscall.stime, nd_syscall.settimeofday, nd_syscall.clock_settime {
    printf("process %d (%s) called %s(%s) at %d\n", pid(), execname(), name, argstr,
           gettimeofday_us());
}

# stap clock.stp
```

To test this, in another window run

```
# date 04301056
Thu Apr 30 10:56:00 EDT 2015
```

and stap's output will be

```
process 7520 (date) called clock_settime(CLOCK_REALTIME, [1430405760.000000000]) at 1430405782997282
```